# How to run a application python not user administrator before create to installer

Tags: python, windows, permissions, installation

I created a installer of an app python 3.4 with innosetup for windows 8.1 and windows 10, but after of installed my application it not working right with normal user, it need administrator user of windows...

It is problem of my installer?, my application? . My application edit to files in installation directory.. txt files anymore.

Comment: You shouldn't be editing files in the installation directory. Standard users aren't allowed to modify system directories such as `%ProgramFiles%`. If you need a data directory accessible by all users, create it in `%ProgramData%`, and modify the directory's permissions to allow standard users to modify files. If the data files are unique to each user, create them in a subdirectory of the user's `%LocalAppData%` or `%AppData%`.

Comment: I  will try it. Thanks :)